# Open a new session to run other application in PHP CLI

Tags: php

I am building a command line application in PHP. At the end of the running process, I would like to run react app like

```
$choice = readline("Wanna run UI? ");

if ($choice == 'y') {
    print `cd /path/to/react-app && yarn start`;
}
```

Issue: Successfully run the app but the PHP stop there waiting for something in response which nothing from React. And the PHP app cannot continue the rest to be needed.

I would like to open a new session in PHP for the command

```
print `cd /path/to/react-app && yarn start`;
```

But simply I don't know what to do, is that possible? I don't know the right term to search on Google.

Comment: Have you tried `nohup`?

Comment: Never heard of it and I will search for that

Comment: If you're running on linux, you could try forking another process to the background using something like this: `exec('bash -c "cd /path/to/react-app && yarn start" 2>&1 >/dev/null &');`.  This will split off another process and allow your PHP code to continue (or exit)